# Remove required field in Grant Application

Tags: civigrant

The Grant module requires "Amount Requested" when entering a grant.  This information may not be available when the grant is created.  Why is this a required field?  How can we make it optional?  Workaround is to make it 0.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a non-coding way to do this. You could try to manipulate the UI with an extension to accept a submission without an amount value. But there may be reasons in the business logic why an amount is required, i.e. you may experience follow-up problems if there are grant records without that value in your database.

So unless this is a serious problem for you, I think your workaround is the best way to go.